# Clarify about the geometric interpretation of the group $H_2(S^2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In class we saw that $H_2(S^2)$ is isomorphic ton $H_1(S^1)$, and the isomorphism is obtained in this way:

- $H_1(S^1)\simeq H_2(D,\partial D)$ by the connecting homomorphism $\delta_2$ of the pair $(D,\partial D)$, where obviously $D$ is the closed two dimensional disk;
- $H_2(D,\partial D)\simeq H_2(D^+, \partial D^+)$, where $D^+$ is the upper (closed) hemisphere of $S^2$ (and so $\partial D^+$ is the equator);
- $H_2(D^+, \partial D^+)\simeq H_2(S^2,D^-)$ because the inclusion $(D^+, \partial D^+) \hookrightarrow (S^2,D^-)$ induces an isomorphism $\alpha$ in homology by the excision theorem.

Until this point is all clear: we have simply said that if we take the generator of $H_1(S^1)$, this is sent by $\delta_2^{-1}$ in the equivalence class of all the disk $D$ in $H_2(D,\partial D)$, and this class is sent by $\alpha$ in the class of $H_2(S^2,D^-)$ with the $2$-chains (of $S^2$) that contain $D^+$ (Call this class $x$). Now comes my problem: consider the projection $S_2(S^2) \twoheadrightarrow S_2(S^2,D^-)$, and call $\pi$ the morphism induced in homology. My teacher said that finally $H_2(S^2,D^-)$ is isomorphic to $H_2(S^2)$ because $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is the whole sphere considered as a class of $H_2(S^2)$. However this doesn't convince me for two reasons:

- heuristically it's clear that $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is the whole sphere, because the sphere itself is the only chain of $S_2(S^2)$ that contain $D^+$ and has no boundary (remember that $\pi$ is defined from $H_2(S^2)$ to $H_2(S^2,D^-)$). However I don't think that we can just assume this evidence as true;
- I'm not convinced also because if we make the same reasoning not with the sphere but with $H_2(D,\partial D)$, which is still isomorphic to $H_2(S^2)$, we can't find an element of the disk that contains the whole disk and has no boundary.

I don't know, it seems to me that this last passage is a forcing, but probably I am misunderstanding something. I know that (always for the excision) one could contract $D^-$ to a point and obtain again $S^2$ (and the same for $\partial D$), but I'd like to uderstand how is reasoning my teacher. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What is "$\pi^{-1}(x)$ is the whole sphere considered as a class of $H_2(S^2)$"? Assuming that the sphere is already regarded as two singular $2$-simplices (imbedded by the identity map) $p_1,p_2$ gluing together, I feel like your description is implying something like $p_1+p_2$ or $p_1-p_2$ is the inverse-image of $x$. Is that what you really want to express? "The whole sphere" is somehow ambiguous......

Comment: @Kevin.S I'm simply saying that the sphere itself can be considered as a $2$-chain of $S^2$, and moreover its boundary is null. I know that these two things must be proved, but we already did it in class and they are not my problem right now.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you work with singular homology. It is not true that "the sphere itself is the only chain of $S_2(S^2)$ that contains $D^+$ and has no boundary". **The sphere is no chain at all.**

A chain is a formal sum of singular simplices, and of course you can define *various* chains triangulating the whole sphere, but (1) this is not unique and (2) also all multiples of such chains have the property mentioned in your question. And it is not at all clear why there shouldn't be also completely different chains with this property. I think heuristics will not help, you need very formal arguments.

The final step is to show that $H_2(S^2,D^-) \approx H_2(S^2)$. This follows from the exact sequence of $(S^2,D^-)$ :

$$ 0 = H_2(D^-) \to H_2(S^2) \to H_2(S^2,D^-) \to H_1(D^-) = 0$$

Comment: The fact that the two groups are isomorphic is clear to me, my problem is about the geometrical interpretation of a generator of $H_2(S^2)$. If I take a generator of $H_2(S^2, D^-)$, how can I say formally that it corresponds (via the isomorphism that you wrote) to the whole sphere in $H_2(S^2)$?

Comment: @Dorian You take a generator of $H_1(S^1)$ and shift it to "the class of $H_2(S^2,D^-)$ with the $2$-chains (of $S^2$) that contain $D^+$" - you should make this precise, i.e. explicitly describe a chain in $S_2(S^2,D^-)$ which represents this class (and prove that your choice is adequate). If you can do that, it will become transparent what the desired generator is.

Comment: I don't know how I could say that more precisely; anyway when I think of that class of $H_2(S^2,D^-)$, I am thinking of an open set in $S^2$ that contains all $D^+$ (that is closed). Now, my problem is that I don't understand how to say formally that $S^2$ itself is the only element of $H_2(S^2)$ sent by the projection in such equivalence class of $H_2(S^2,D^-)$.

Comment: @Dorian Singular chains are not the same as open subsets $U \subset S^2$ or $S^2$ itself. You can *triangulate* $U$ and $S^2$ and get associated singular chains (where each singular simplex has multiplicity $1$). This may be taken an intuitive intepretation of $U$ and $S^2$ as a chain, but you should  aware that these chains are not unique and that it is highly nontrivial to prove that all these special chains are homologous.

Comment: Of course when I talked about an open set of $S^2 $ I was considering it as a chain of simplexes as you said.  However maybe I expressed badly my problem: consider the group $H^2(S^2,D^-)$ and take the equivalence class of $D^+$, which is easily a $2$-chain of $S^2$. Now, consider the projection $\pi:H^2(S^2) \to H^2(S^2,D^-)$; I know that $S^2\subset H^2(S^2)$ is the only element whose image via $\pi$ is $D^+\subset H^2(S^2,D^-)$, but I don't understand how to see it formally